# What's the largest n such that any 3-connected graph of order n is hamiltonian?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonicity

I've figured out it's true for $n$ up to 6, using Ore's theorem. I'm not sure how to find an example of a non-hamiltonian 3-connected graph.

Comment: A complete bipartite graph $K_{3,4}$ is a $3$-connected non-Hamiltonian graph. It has $7$ of vertices.

Comment: This generalizes: $K_{3,a}$ is 3-connected and non-Hamiltonian for $a \geq 4$. So the answer is 6. Thanks!